# use TikZ markers outside of plot operation / use math symbols as markers

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I ask this question more to have suggestions than to solve a real problem.

When I have to plot data I use pgfplots. On the other hand, in order to keep the code smaller, I use tikz in other situations, e.g. when I have to make grids like the one coded in following non-MWE

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,5}
    \foreach \y in {0,1,...,5}
    \draw plot[only marks,mark=o] coordinates{(\x,\y)};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Such a basic `tikzpicture` (which would get "fat" adding `\begin{axis}` and other stuff like that) could be even slimmer substituting the fourth line by `\node at (\x,\y) {$\circ$};` (I know the result is a little bit different), that is

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,5}
    \foreach \y in {0,1,...,5}
    \node at (\x,\y) {$\circ$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Whichever the code chosen, it has to be put in a `figure`, whose caption could be required to refer to a specific marker of the `tikzpicture` (if more than one are present).
Obviously it's easy to refer to `$\circ$` in the text. Furthermore I would prefer to use symbols like `$\circ$`, `$\bullet$` and similia, since they're constant in size when the `tikzpicture` is made bigger or smaller.
On the other hand, markers can be easily changed in color, shape and can be filled, rotated and so on. So the question arises: is it easy to refer to a mark of a `plot` operation in `\draw`? And how to do it the best way?

Thank you in advice for suggestions

**EDIT:**
I don't need an actual reference since I know that I will reference this symbols only once, just in the caption below the figure. For this reason, to "reference" a `$\circ$`, I simply write `$\circ$` in the caption. The point is: if I use `\draw plot[only marks,mark=o] coordinates{(\x,\y)};`, how can I easily (if it is possible) reproduce manually the marker in the text outside the `tikzpicture`? (Maybe it's worth to mention that I don't want to use ref/label to plots in order to avoid externalization problems)

**EDIT 2:**
The picture I typeset at the moment is the following.
[image]

and it is coded as follows

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (-.25,-.25) grid (5.25,5.25);
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,5}
    \foreach \y in {.5,1.5,...,5}
    \node at (\x,\y) {\tiny$\blacktriangleright$};

    \foreach \x in {.5,1.5,...,5}
    \foreach \y in {0,1,...,5}
    \node[rotate=90] at (\x,\y) {\tiny$\blacktriangleright$};

    \foreach \x in {.5,1.5,...,5}
    \foreach \y in {.5,1.5,...,5}
    \node at (\x,\y) {$\circ$};

    \node[rotate=0] at (2.5,5.5) {\raisebox{1pt}{\tiny$\blacktriangleright$} $u$ \hspace{.5cm} \rotatebox{90}{\raisebox{1pt}{\tiny$\blacktriangleright$}} $v$ \hspace{.5cm} $\circ$ $p$};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

where I used a handmade legend.

- Doing so I both handle the picture without pgfplots (I don't need so much power) and avoid using actual `\ref/\label`s that I'm not able to handle in conjunction with externalization.
- The drawback in using symbols is that I can not customize them: they're many, but markers are virtually in infinite number (e.g. `$\bullet$` is not properly the filled version of `$\circ$`, as it happens for `mark=*` and `mark=o`; symbols are one-color, whereas markers can be two-colors; and so on).

This is why I was thinking about `\draw plot[only marks,mark=o] coordinates{(\x,\y)};`...

Hope to have set the question.

Comment: You want to refer to it like, `The node \ref{name} is...`? Because in that case, I'd suggest using `pgfplots`.

Comment: No, no. Figurures like that have not to be explained more than once (in the caption), so there's no need to create references. Just to use the same symbol in both the figure and the caption.

Comment: How do you mean referring?

Comment: If I used `$\circ$`, then I would use `\caption{The symbol $\circ$ indicates the points where bla bla bla.}` in the `figure` environment.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis `\caption{The symbol $\circ$ ...` can't work because Latex wouldn't know what you're referencing. Unless you want it to be manual, like [this example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/W8I2B.png).

Comment: Yes, I want it to be manual, since I "reference" it only once.

Answer (score 2):

Markers are small fragments of low level TikZ drawings. So you can refer to them via PGF notation.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\def\myplotmark#1{%
  \begin{pgfpicture}\pgfuseplotmark{#1}\end{pgfpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}%
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (-.25,-.25) grid (5.25,5.25);
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,5}
    \foreach \y in {.5,1.5,...,5}
%    \node at (\x,\y) {\tiny$\blacktriangleright$};
    \draw plot[only marks,mark=triangle*,mark options={rotate=-90}] coordinates{(\x,\y)};


    \foreach \x in {.5,1.5,...,5}
    \foreach \y in {0,1,...,5}
%    \node[rotate=90] at (\x,\y) {\tiny$\blacktriangleright$};
    \draw plot[only marks,mark=triangle*] coordinates{(\x,\y)};

    \foreach \x in {.5,1.5,...,5}
    \foreach \y in {.5,1.5,...,5}
%    \node at (\x,\y) {$\circ$};
    \draw plot[only marks,mark=o] coordinates{(\x,\y)};

%    \node[rotate=0] at (2.5,5.5) {\raisebox{1pt}{\tiny$\blacktriangleright$} 
%        $u$ \hspace{.5cm} \rotatebox{90}{\raisebox{1pt}{\tiny$\blacktriangleright$}} 
%        $v$ \hspace{.5cm} $\circ$ $p$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Here are some markers: 
\protect\myplotmark{triangle*} and 
\protect\myplotmark{triangle*} and 
\protect\myplotmark{o}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I don't have access to TeX now so I couldn't test the `\protect`less version. Please feel free to edit or fix.

Comment: I edited it just a bit. I think you got the point. Furthermore I see that `\myplotmark` are not externalized, just as I want. The last point to fix is how to rotate them. As you can see form my editing, the second and third markers in the caption match those in the second and third  `\draw plot`s, whereas the first don't, for being not rotated. Where should I add `mark options={rotate=-90}`?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by externalised but you can enhance the macro with an additional argument that goes into `\tikzset{}` before the `\pgfuseplotmark`. But you are reinventing the wheel. `pgfplots` does this right off the bat including line types, width and many more.

Comment: (About the externalization I simply mean this: if markers are low level TikZ drawings I would expect them to be externalized if externalization is enabled, but they don't. Nothing more.)
Maybe you're right about the wheel.. Maybe I should simply use pgfplots. It simply sounds so strange to me to use it to make sketches. Pgfplots is meant to be used to plot functions, not to draw sketches, isn't it?

Comment: Use `tikzpicture` environment and they will be externalised as tiny PDF files. It requires slightly more work for `pgfpicture` to externalise

Comment: No, no. As I wrote it's "just as I want".

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis I am really having problems following your line of thought. I think you can simplify your question to a single marker in a tikzpicture and in a caption and state what needs to be done instead of externalisations and sketches and terminology of your own. Every marker with every option is available outside the plot command as I showed. They are simply TikZ drawings and hence available everywhere.  You are asking a pretty specific combination of these but in a very convoluted fashion.

Comment: I've already done what I want. I was simply trying to understand if there's a better way to do it, considering: 1) pgfplots is for plotting data (isn't it?), tikz is more general and the figure is a sketch, not a plot of data; 2) there are a lot of customizable markers, whereas the symbols like circ, bullet, and so on are not; 3) symbols are not tikzpictures so they're not involved in externalization; 4) the use of markers is available by `\draw plot` without the use of pgfplots' `axis` environment; 5) other aspects, for instance those concerning baseline of symbols..